# Share code between react application(expo) and react native application

Tags: reactjs, react-native

We are setting up a new project and we want to create shared library. This should share code between react and react-native.

What is the simplest way to share code between both?

We are looking for something like this:
-web
-mobile
-shared (all shared code goes here)

We want to start with simple code to share "Button". We want all branding to be in shared like colors etc.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on your culture and how you already organise your projects and files. What is important is that it's as simple as sharing any JS files.

But, when you talk about sharing the branding and style information, you will first have to decide on how to manage styles on RN. That will have a huge impact on your ability to share or not some data.

That said, one option is to have a multi-repo and have a shared folder in a higher level than the other two projects. A second option would be sharing that folder as a git module. A third, that might give you some extra work, would be as a npm module.

Comment: Currently, all I am looking for is this:
-web
-mobile
-shared

I want to read from shared folder in both web and mobile. How can I achieve that?